Continuous function from a product topological space to a sum topological space
I denote by $\mathbf{2}$ the set $\{0, 1\}$ that is given the discrete topology. Let $X$ be some topological space. I denote by $\mathbf{2} \times X$ the topological space with the product topology and by $X + X$ the topological space with the sum topology (the two spaces have the same points).
By the universal property of the product topological space there are two continuous functions $f_0, f_1: X \to \mathbf{2} \times X$ such that $\pi_2 \circ f_0 = id_X = \pi_2 \circ f_1$ ($\pi_2$ is the second projection $\mathbf{2} \times X \to X$) and $\pi_1 \circ f_0$ is the constant function that returns $0$ and $\pi_1 \circ f_1$ is the constant function that returns $1$ ($\pi_1$ is the first projection $\mathbf{2} \times X \to \mathbf{2}$). Notice that, for any $j \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, for any $x \in X$, we have $f_j(x) = (j, x)$.
By the universal property of the sum topological space there is a continuous function $k: X + X \to \mathbf{2} \times X$ such that $k \circ \iota_0 = f_0$ and $k \circ \iota_1 = f_1$ ($\iota_0$ and $\iota_1$ are the two coprojecctions $X \to X + X$). Notice that, for any $j \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, for any $x \in X$, we have $k((j, x)) = (k \circ \iota_j) (x) = f_j(x) = (j, x)$, that is: $k$ is just the identity function.
The universal properties of the product topological space and of the sum topological space show that the identity function is a continuous function $X + X \to \mathbf{2} \times X$. I would like to show that the identity function is a continuous function $\mathbf{2} \times X \to X + X$ (which would show that $X + X = \mathbf{2} \times X$). One possible way is to show that any open set of $X + X$ is an open set of $\mathbf{2} \times X$ but is there an "abstract" way to show it ("abstract" in the sense that it relies on the universal properties, like for the existence of $k$)?

There is a limit to the level of abstraction at which this can be proved, since this is essentially about proving the distributivity identity $(1 + 1) \times X \cong (1 \times X) + (1 \times X)$. There are categories where all these terms are always defined, but this identity fails badly, such as the category of (abelian) groups. There is some further reading here, here, here, here.
